# Laravel eloquent JSON field, selecting attribute produces extra double quote

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

This code:

```
$translation = Translation::where('language_id', 2)
            ->whereNotNull('data->navigation_login')
            ->select('data->navigation_login as navigation_login')
            ->first()
            ->toArray();
dd($translation);
```

Produces this result:
`array(1) {["navigation_login"]=> string(7) ""Login"" }`

**The problem is the extra double quote arround the login string: `""Login""`**

How can I eliminate this?

If I run the above code without select:

```
$translation = Translation::where('language_id', 2)
            ->whereNotNull('data->navigation_login')
            ->first()
            ->toArray();
dd($translation);
```

No double quotes:

```
["data"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["navigation_login"]=>
    string(5) "Login"
    ["navigation_order"]=>
    string(5) "Order"
    ["navigation_registration"]=>
    string(7) "Sign up"
  }
```

Here is the model detail:

```
...
class Translation extends Model {

    protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'array',
    ];
...
```

Here is the schema detail:

```
...
$table->json('data')->nullable();
...
```

Comment: Can you put dot instead of -> in data->navigation_login this line?

Comment: Is the table for Translation model really called 'data'? Could you include some info on table schema?

Comment: @DrStein `->select('data.navigation_login as navigation_login')` The dot is not work. **Unknown column 'data.navigation_login'**

Comment: @MartinJoiner I updated the question.

Comment: maybe it is a bug in laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally the solution:

**MySQL 5.7.13 and later**

[Using the unquoting extraction operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) ->>

`->select('data->>navigation_login as navigation_login')`

Or older mysql version  5.7 < MYSQL < 5.7.13

`->select(\DB::raw("JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.navigation_login')) as navigation_login"))`

Comment: And how would it be for an json type array? '["a", "b", "c"]'

->select('data->>[1] as data')... this not work